# NSAppleScript Returned Value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, applescript, nsmenuitem

How do I get the returned value from an NSAppleScript.
I am using apple script to get the song title in iTunes and take that value and set NSMenuItem's title.

My code: .M

```
//run applescript
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application      \"iTunes\" to set song to name of current track"];
[script executeAndReturnError:nil];
//set menu item title
[songName setTitle:script];
```

My code: .H

```
IBOutlet NSMenuItem *songName;
```

Comment: This is not a complete question. What happens when you run your code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @DustinRowland nothing happens when I run the code the code _is_ what I have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a `NSAppleEventDescriptor` when you execute a `NSAppleScript` (not a **NSString**.

```
NSAppleEventDescriptor *theResult = [script executeAndReturnError:nil];
//set menu item title
[songName setTitle:[theResult stringValue]];
```